# Making boundary condition a variable in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, functions, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions, mathematica-online

I would like to make where my ODE is evaluated at (not the boundary condition itself but rather the "x" value of the boundary condition) to be a variable in my code. I find that Mathematica complains that it cannot find a starting value for ParametricNDSolve. My code is as follows:

```
    a321 = {-7, -(19/6), 41/10};


    b321 =  {
        {-26, 9/2, 11/10},
       {12, 35/6, 9/10},
        {44/5, 27/10, 199/50}
       } ;

    ainv3221[u_] = {1/v4[u], 1/v3[u], 1/v2[u], 1/v1[u]};

    
   sol = ParametricNDSolve[{
        v4'[u] - 
          1/u Part[-(a3221/(2 \[Pi])) - 
             1/(8 \[Pi]^2) b3221 .ainv3221[u], 1] == 0,
         v3'[u] - 
          1/u Part[-(a3221/(2 \[Pi])) - 
             1/(8 \[Pi]^2) b3221 .ainv3221[u], 2] == 0,
        v2'[u] - 
          1/u Part[-(a3221/(2 \[Pi])) - 
             1/(8 \[Pi]^2) b3221 . ainv3221[u], 3] == 0,
        v1'[u] - 
          1/u Part[-(a3221/(2 \[Pi])) - 
             1/(8 \[Pi]^2) b3221 . ainv3221[u], 4] == 0,
        v4[t] == b1,
        v3[t] == b2,
        v2[t] == b3, 
        v1[t] == b4},
     {v1, v2, v3, v4}, {u, 10^1, 10^17}, {t, b1, b2, b3, 
        b4}];
    v1sol[t_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_] := v1[t, b1, b2, b3, b4][u] /. sol;
    v2sol[t_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_] := v2[t, b1, b2, b3, b4][u] /. sol;
     v3sol[t_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_] := v3[t, b1, b2, b3, b4][u] /. sol;
    v4sol[t_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_] := v4[t, b1, b2, b3, b4][u] /. sol;
```

I would like to get v1sol, v2sol, v3sol and v4sol such that I can vary where the boundary condition are satisfied. Varying the boundary condition itself (say b1 = 34, b2 = 45, b3 = 55, b4 = 65) is not a problem but varying "t" is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `sol[t_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_] := NDSolve[...`.

Comment: I did but that also don't allow you to make the boundary condition (or where the boundary is evaluated) a variable

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: By the way, `a3221` and `b3221` are undefined, and `a321` and `b321`have a different dimension than `ainv3221`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation of the suggestion I made in my comment last night.

```
s[x0_] := NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1, y[x0] == 0}, y[x], {x, 0, 5}]
Table[s[n], {n, 0, 5}];
Plot[%, {x, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

If you wish to vary both the value and location of the boundary condition, use

```
s[x0_, y0_] := NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == 1, y[x0] == y0}, y[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a shot!